# Difference between APK downloaded and installed from browser and APK installed using drag and drop

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any difference when APK is installed from browser and APK installed using drag and drop in Android emulator

I tried to install apk using ADB and got following output when verifying APK using apksigner

> ## DOES NOT VERIFY ERROR: APK Signature Scheme v2 signer #1: APK integrity check failed. CHUNKED_SHA256 digest mismatch. Expected:
>
> ,
>   actual:
>   <9272e790e85bbc96cb9499621e3425924e040650720530908ae9abe27daea7a5> 
>   #

This clearly implies that APK needs to be signed using V2 schema.

Strangely I downloaded APK in simulator using browser and when I tried to installed. It installed successfully.

Can anyone explain the exact difference between these two scenarios?